# Convert django loader.render_to_string() to flask for sendgrid

Tags: python, flask

We are converting our django app to flask and I cannot find something like the django loader.render_to_string for flask.

Any suggestions I tried the render_template_string in flask but to no avail?

```
from django.template import loader
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient

def send_email:
    dt = {
        'name': xxxxxx,
        'application_name': xxxxxx,
    }

    email_template_text = loader.render_to_string("xxxxx.txt", dt)
    email_template_html = loader.render_to_string("xxxxx.html", dt)

    data = {
        "personalizations": [
            {
                "to": [
                    {
                        "email": xxxxx
                    }
                ],
                "subject": xxxxxx
            }
        ],
        "from": {
            "email": xxxxxxx
        },
        "content": [
            {
                "type": "text/plain",
                "value":  email_template_text
            },
            {
                "type": "text/html",
                "value": email_template_html
            }
        ]
    }
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(xxxxx)
    response = sg.send(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`flask.render_template` <sup>[[1](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0.3/flask/templating.py#L122)]</sup> should suffice for the result you expect.

Remember to unpack the dictionary for the context parameters of the template.

Also, this must be done in the context of flask application.
Where this is a possibly run by a worker your code will look similar to:

```py
from flask import render_template, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    email_template_text = render_template("xxxxx.txt", **dt)
    email_template_html = render_template("xxxxx.html", **dt)
```